# Spring prototype scope with autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, autowired

I have a class `JobListener` that is listening to a queue using Spring Integration. Inside `JobListener`, i have an `Autowired` field `Helper` whose scope is defined as "prototype".

```
public class JobListener {

@Autowired
private Helper helper;

@ServiceActivator
public void receiveMessage(Message<String> message){
    helper.processMassage(message);
    }
}
```

Now my question is, Since the scope of Helper is defined as `Protype`, will i get a new instance of helper every time `recieveMessage` is called?

Comment: fast answer, no, when JobListener is created by spring framework it will autowire the helper, at class creation, but each other class with a reference to a Helper, will have a different instance

Comment: inside receiveMessage `helper = (Helper)context.getBean("helper");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The container only creates the singleton bean `JobListener` once, and thus only gets one opportunity to set the properties. The container cannot provide bean `JobListener` with a new instance of bean `Helper` every time one is needed.

One solution to this problem is to use `Method Injection`:  `Lookup method injection` is the ability of the container to override methods on container managed beans, to return the lookup result for another named bean in the container. To implement this solution, re-define the `JobListener` class as this:

```
public abstract class JobListener {

@ServiceActivator
public void receiveMessage(Message<String> message){
    Helper helper = createHelper();
    helper.processMassage(message);
    }

protected abstract Helper createHelper();
}
```

The Spring Framework will generate a dynamic subclass of `JobListener` that will override the `createHelper` method to provide a new instance of `Helper` every time it is requested for.

You need to define the name of `lookup-method` name in the `JobListener` bean definition:

```
<bean id="helper" class="x.y.Helper" scope="prototype">
...
</bean>

<bean id="jobListener" class="x.y.JobListener">
<lookup-method name="createHelper" bean="helper"/>
</bean>
```

With the above configurations in place, every time you execute

```
Helper helper = createHelper();
```

it will return you a new instance of `Helper`.

Comment: Thanks all for help. Your prompt replies saved a lot of time and rework.